# Plotting problems - mishandling factor variable as numeric

Tags: r, plot, graph, graphing

I am not entirely sure what to name the problem I am having with the plotting function in R...

In my original dataset I had a variable called age with these levels: 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 2X, 30, 40, 50, 60. When I would plot age using:

```
plot(age, xlab="Age", ylab="Number of observations")
```

I would then get this plot (a bar plot with age on the x-axis and number of observations on the y-axis):

[image: Plot with 2X in the data]

I then removed 2X (for people somewhere in their 20's) from the data and used the same code above to get the new plot. When I re-ran the code the plot now looks like this (a plot with age on the y-axis):

[image: Plot without 2X in the data]

If anyone has any ideas about why the plot now has the age on the y-axis, please let me know! Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How did you "remove 2X"? What class is `age`? Did it change class before and after you removed 2X? What does `str(age)` look like before and after? If you could share a small amount of your data reproducibly - just enough to illustrate the problem - it would go a long way to solving this. [Please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for tips on reproducibly sharing data.

Comment: I removed "2X" points by deleting them from the original Excel file and then saving a new .txt file. Before the "2x" points were removed, the `str(age)` output was: `Factor w/ 22 levels "15","16","17",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...`. After the "2x" points were removed, the `str(age)` output was: `int [1:45816] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 …`. I will try to get some data ready based on those guidelines too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Diagnostic**

You are getting into S3 methods dispatch issues. `plot` is a generic function:

```
methods(plot)
# [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts*
# [4] plot.default        plot.dendrogram*    plot.density*      
# [7] plot.ecdf           plot.factor*        plot.formula*      
#[10] plot.function       plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*    
#[13] plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*        plot.lm*           
#[16] plot.medpolish*     plot.mlm*           plot.ppr*          
#[19] plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*      plot.profile.nls*  
#[22] plot.raster*        plot.spec*          plot.stepfun       
#[25] plot.stl*           plot.table*         plot.ts            
#[28] plot.tskernel*      plot.TukeyHSD*
```

Comments above asked you to provide `str(age)` before and after removing `2X`, because such information helps tell which method has been dispatched when `plot` is called.

When you have `2X` data, `age` is definitely a factor. So when you call `plot`, `plot.factor` is invoked and a bar plot is produced.

While when you removed `2X`, it seems that `age` somehow becomes a numerical variable. So when you call `plot`, `plot.default` is invoked and a scatter plot is produced, in which case `plot(age)` is essentially doing `plot.default(1:length(age), age)`.

---

**Solution**

One way that would definitely work is

```
plot(factor(age), xlab="Age", ylab="Number of observations")
```

However, I am still curious how you removed `2X` subset so that `age` becomes numeric. Normally if `age` is a factor variable in R, removing a subset does not change variable class.

Presumably `age` is stored in a `.txt` or `.csv` file and you read it via `scan()`, `read.table()` or `read.csv()`. When you remove `2X`, you removed them in those files and read data into R again. In this way, R will identify `age` to be a different class at data read-in time.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how you could get `plot.default` to produce *that particular* scatter plot ... ?

Comment: I stored the data in a `.txt` file and read it via `read.table()`.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: I clicked the grey tick mark (arrow up) and it gave it one vote, but it did not turn green. Am I missing something?